# Change /path/index.html to /path/ with nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

in my current lightspeed server I use the following code to use `/path/index.html` to `/pathg/` or `/path/example.html` to `/path/example/`

```
# to make `/path/index.html` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Does anyone knnow how to achive the same thing using nginx?

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: Well, I do not have any idea where to start actually. Thats why I asked you guys if you can help. I'm very new to nginx.

Comment: For now it looks like you want us to write whole config for you.

Comment: No I dont want that. I know thats against the rule of stackoverflow. I'm asking for some similar codes or articles which might help me to solve my issue.

Comment: There are thousands ".htaccess to nginx" questions

Comment: yes but that are not related to my issue. Thats the problem I've already seen most of them before posting the question.